# Is it possible to change "Device broadcast status" of spotify app from another app?

Tags: android, spotify

I am trying to access the "Now Playing" data from Spotify app. However, I don't want to warn the user about he/she needs to change this setting from Spotify app, it might be bad user experience.

Is is possible to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Since this broadcasts data the user might deem private, it's a setting that has to be enabled manually by the user.